# How do I exclude certain modules from a Maven build using the commandline

Tags: maven, maven-module

Is there a way to exclude some modules from a big reactor build, similar to -pl ?

Here are a number of ways to do it persistently:

[How to exclude a module from a Maven reactor build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539348/how-to-exclude-a-module-from-a-maven-reactor-build)

I want to do it from shell, or at least without modifying the poms, which I am not allowed to change.

Comment: Using profiles seems to be the easiest and most correct way to me.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov can that be done in settings.xml ? Switching off tests per profile will not be appreciated in central poms. ;-)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Maven 3.2.1 has added this feature, you can use to specify the exact projects you want (or to exclude the projects you don't want) `-pl` or `--projects` Here's how to exclude two:

```
-pl "!<modulename>,!<modulename2>"
```

for exclude certain modules. This can be comma separated list of values that you want to include/exclude.

**Update**
For windows user following

```sh
> mvn clean [package|install] --projects \!groupId:artifactId
```

Comment: !<modulename> is not work in window. is there different key word ! for window?

Comment: @bNd on windows you have to mention '!<groupId>:<artifactId>' of particular module even if it is a submodule

Comment: `<modulename>` is the directory name of the submodule, not the artifactId

Answer (score 66):

Another comment on the accepted answer, don't forget to escape the exclamation sign when running the command in bash:

```
> mvn clean install -pl \!module,\!module/submodule,\!groupId:artifactId
```

Comment: or surround with quotes :)

Comment: Single quotes ('), that is

Comment: thanks @dstibbe `mvn clean -pl '!module'` did the trick for me

Comment: or use `-` instead of `!`, i.e. `> mvn clean install -pl -module,-module/submodule,-groupId:artifactId`

Answer (score 19):

As Yogesh_D wrote it can be done with the -pl argument with maven 3.2.1+

Here's an example:

```
> mvn clean install -amd -pl !module,!module/submodule
```

You need to list every sub-module (and sub-sub-module etc) manually, it does not exclude them recursively. Use the slash for package separation. It's the folder path, not the group or artifact id.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this is currently possible from the command line.  There is an open feature request in maven3 for this very thing (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5230).

Looks like your only option at this point is to modify the pom and create a new build profile that includes only the modules you want to build.

Comment: Jira link is dead

Comment: MNG-5230 - was resolved in version maven 3.2.1

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using exclamation `!` sign you can use minus `-` sign.

```
mvn clean -pl -module1
```

You can also exclude multiple modules.

```
mvn clean -pl -module1,-module2
```

or

```
mvn clean -pl -module1 -pl -module2
```

Tested with:

- Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T20:33:14+02:00)
- Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)

Excluded modules must be in reactor of current project, so we can't exclude no existing module.

```
mvn clean -pl -no-existing-module
```

currently will fail - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7033

Answer (score 1):

in 2019 it's

```
mvn install -pl !:module1
```

(Windows 10 cmd)

Answer (score -2):

comma separated module name enclosed with double quotes.
 eg::

```
mvn install -pl "!Module1, !Module2"
```