# How can I exclude a project from a mvn clean install?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-install-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I exclude certain modules from a maven build using the commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266470/how-do-i-exclude-certain-modules-from-a-maven-build-using-the-commandline)

I am running a `maven clean install` in a pom file which includes several modules (and sub-modules). I was wondering if it is possible to run a maven build but specifying on command line to skip a module from the build ( at the moment I exclude them manually from the build, but Id prefer to do it via command line).

I know that with -pl you can selectively choose projects, but what I would like is to selectively exclude (in a blacklist fashion) some.

Comment: This was just asked the other day.  In short there isn't a way to do this from the command line... yet.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13266470/73446

Comment: Somehow I missed that question on my search

Answer (score 6):

You could have a separate `<modules>` section in a profile, and activate the profile you need in the command line.

Example:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
       <id>profile-1</id>
       <activation>
         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
       </activation>
       <modules>...</modules> <!-- module set 1 -->
    </profile>
    <profile>
       <id>profile-2</id>
       <modules>...</modules> <!-- module set 2 -->
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now, dependent on your current need, execute

```
mvn install
mvn install -P profile-2
```

Note that you'd have to think it over carefully, there must be no cross-profile dependencies on the excluded module.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was really looking for a command line solution where I do not need to Crete profiles or touch the pom. Apparently there isn't one yet :(

Comment: Excluding a project is not a trivial case for Maven, so I'll venture a guess that it will never be as simple as a command line option.