# How to exclude a single module from Javadoc generation in a Maven multi module project?

Tags: maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a Maven multi module project like this:

```
foo-parent
    foo-module
    foo-module-new
    foo-other-module1
    foo-other-module2
    pom.xml
```

And when calling `mvn javadoc:aggregate` in foo-parent, I want to exclude the module *foo-module* from Javadoc generation.

Exclusion by package name with the parameter `excludePackageNames` doesn't work in my case because foo-module and foo-module-new have the same package name.

Comment: After reading [this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.turbine.maven.user/134446), it seems the only way to do it is to use a profile, like the current answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `maven-javadoc-plugin:3.2.0` you can use the [`skippedModules`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html#skippedModules) property to provide a comma separated list of modules to skip. For instance the following configuration would skip the `foo-module` module:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <reportSets>
    <reportSet>
      <id>aggregate</id>
      <configuration>
        <skippedModules>foo-module</skippedModules>
      </configuration>
    </reportSet>
  </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

Alternatively, you may use the `maven.javadoc.skippedModules` user property to achieve the same outcome.

Answer (score 6):

Launch the following to generate javadocs only for `foo-other-module1` and `foo-other-module2` modules (note: always include the aggregator module, in this case `foo-parent`):

```
mvn javadoc:aggregate -pl :foo-parent,:foo-other-module1,:foo-other-module2
```

**Since Maven 3.2.1**, you can also exclude modules from your reactor, so the above simplifies to

```
mvn javadoc:aggregate -pl '!foo-module'
```

Comment: I think you are correct: Specifying the projects on the modules on the command line is currently the best option. Although I would have preferred to keep this logic in the pom.xml.

Comment: Also note that [exclusion is possible since Maven 3.2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266470/how-do-i-exclude-certain-modules-from-a-maven-build-using-the-commandline/22783633#22783633) And it seems to work without the colon in front of the module name.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you change it to exclusion instead of inclusion. I really think that's the better option in this case.

Comment: For all people unable to read thoroughly (like me): The answer states explicitly that you have to add the parent module to the list of modules meant to be included. Otherwise the aggregate still contains the Javadocs from the complete project. If you understand this right from the beginning, it might save you a whole day...

Comment: Either escape the ! with \ or surround it with single quotes. 
mvn javadoc:aggregate -pl \!foo-module 
OR
mvn javadoc:aggregate -pl '!foo-module'

Answer (score 1):

Use maven profile.

1. add in your pom :

   ```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
        <id>javadoc</id>
        <modules>
            <module>module_include_javadoc1</module>
            <module>module_include_javadoc2</module>
        </modules>        
        </profile>
      </profiles>
   ```
2. Run this:

   ```
    mvn javadoc:aggregate -Pjavadoc
   ```

Comment: In this simple form, the answer won't work if all modules are specified at the top of the parent pom. Which is needed for a normal, non-Javadoc build. Generally I think a solution with profiles will be too messy. There's no easy way to exclude a module from a profile.

Comment: Here's a more detailed answer on [how to exclude a module from a Maven reactor build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539348/how-to-exclude-a-module-from-a-maven-reactor-build/11429945#11429945).