# Skip compilation in gmavenplus plugin

Tags: maven, gmaven-plugin

I currently work in big project built by Maven which has many integration tests modules which are marked as **main** (not testing) sources. 
I am trying to create a profile which would skip compilation of these modules.
I expected gmaven plugin to allow "skip" configuration parameter but this is not the case.
Is there any way to skip module processing without pointing gmaven plugin to non-existent directory and without copy-paste of all modules except integration tests to a separate profile?

Comment: dont understand your question ! you use org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the integration test modules in a separate profile of the parent pom where you list the modules. The profile should be active unless you disable it by setting a property when running the Maven build (`-DskipIntegrationTestModules`). ([Don't use activeByDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7481347/1095318).)

```
  <modules>
    <module>my-project</module>
  </modules>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-integration-tests</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!skipIntegrationTestModules</name>
            </property>
        </activation>       
        <modules>
            <module>my-project-integration-test</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

You can find more details in the [Maven Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

You should also know that [it can be dangerous to have modules in build profiles](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/) because they could be accidentally left out when doing release builds. I think it should be OK in this case because the profile has to be deactivated explicitly.

Comment: Sorry is on the question